# Converting 5D cell containing 1x5 double elements into matrix

Tags: matlab, double, cell, data-conversion

I have a cell which is of dim x{5,5,5,7,4} and each element it contains is a 1x5 double. I want to convert x from cell to matrix or double. Now when I open x it just says the elements are 1x5 double. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your elements are `1x5` `double` arrays, then you can use `cat` (combined with `{:}` indexing)  to concatenate all contents along the first dimension

```
result = cat(1, x{:})
```

Comment: But some of them are NaN. Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @user3309191 a `NaN` is still a `double` so it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with a combination of [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) or feval  and cell2mat, which gives you a matrix out of a cell.

You can only use cell2mat on the 'second-lowest' level of the cell, so in this solution you would have to iterate through 4 the 5 dimensions of your cell to give every second-lowest-level cell x{k}{l}{m}{n} a name like 'M_int2str(k)_int2str(l)_int2str(m)_int2str(n)' with eval. After that, concatenate the resulting 5*5*5*7 matrices in a way you would like it.

Another - probably easier and faster - possibility would be to create a cell-pyramid with cell2mat. A shorter example:

```
C={{[1,2,3],[4,5,6]},{[7,8,9],[10,11,12]}};

for k=1:2
    M{k}=cell2mat(C{k});
end

N=cell2mat(M)
```

The result of this is

```
N =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this.